# Saving field updates that are triggered by an OnSave event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm in the process of customizing our CRM solution, but I've run into a problem today.  I have a JavaScript that is triggered by the OnSave event.  This JavaScript updates a field in the form, and tries to save again.

When the script executes, I can see the field I'm trying to update change, but when the form reloads, that field still has its old value.  I've put a little bit of sudo code below.  Has any one else ever had this problem?

OnSave

```
//Update field 
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname").setValue(value);  
//Set submit mode to always 
Xrm.Page.getAttribute.setSubmitMode("always");  
//Force save 
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

Answer (score 4):

If your posted code has no copy/paste errors, I think this line causes your problem

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute.setSubmitMode("always");
```

This should be

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname").setSubmitMode("always");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @ckeller.  I made that change, but I'm still having the same issue.  I believe I've got some sort of race condition occuring.  If I use a very short script that runs onsave, then any updated fields are saved and display correctly in the PostRetrieve.  But when I use this more complex script that queries some other entities (and therefore takes longer), none of the updates stick in the PostRetrieve.

Comment: I actually figured out how to get around this.  By preventing the Save event, and then checking to see if the updated fields are dirty or not, I was able to force the save after updating the values.

Comment: Have come across this problem myself, I believe this is occurring due to Async JS? Is anyone aware of a better way of handling this?. Seems silly to have to prevent the save and then re call save in a callback especially if its only doing some simple updates.

Answer (score 1):

My answer was no answer more of a cry for help it self. Sorry.

As I stated in I would check the order of setting de submitmode and changing of the value. As it appears you must set the submitmode first and then assign a value.

Now my changes are saved.